# Propiedades en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una duda respecto a las propiedades de **C#** con esta linea:

```
public int Ataque { get; set; }
```

¿Esto crea también una variable `ataque`? O simplemente es para acortar el `get` y `set`. Y debería de colocarlo de esta forma:

```
int ataque;
public int Ataque { get; set; }
```

Por que me han comentado que por guía de estilos, las propiedades han de ponerse en mayúsculas, y las variables en minúsculas. Y eso me lía un poco...

Comment: Eso crea intrinsecamente una variable.. es mas.. la segunda version no usa la variable ataque que definiste antes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Efectivamente,

```
public int Ataque { get; set; }
```

es una forma **abreviada** de crear una propiedad, que internamente está gestionada como si existiera una variable `private int ataque`.

Por otra parte, también puedes crear la propiedad de la forma "clásica" con su **variable privada** asociada:

```
    private int ataque;

    public int Ataque
    {
        get { return ataque; }
        set { ataque = value; }
    }
```

Y en cuanto a la convención, las **variables privadas** comenzarían con **minúscula**, y las **propiedades** con **mayúscula**.

Comment: Me ganaste, estaba armando una respuesta similar. Buena respuesta!.

Comment: @CamiloBernal Jaja.. Aquí hay que ser más rápido que en salvaje oeste. ;)